# Robot jumps after the initial estimate with gmapping

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, ros-melodic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a gmapping SLAM method coupled with robot_localization to provide the map-odom, odom-base_footprint transformation respectively (ROS1).

When I power up the system, the generated map is quite accurate, however, after around 10s and without moving the robot, the robot suddenly jumps to another place, destroying the map.

Before:
[image: image description]

After:
[image: image description]

Does anyone know where this jump comes from?

Thank you in advance.

gmapping config file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/> <!--scan_filtered-->
  <arg name="namespace" default="spraybase"/>
  
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">

    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg namespace)/odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg namespace)/base_footprint"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="$(arg namespace)/map"/>

    <!-- Process 1 out of every this many scans (set it to a higher number to skip more scans)  -->
    <param name="throttle_scans" value="1"/>

    <param name="map_update_interval" value="0.1"/> <!-- default: 5.0 -->

    <!-- The maximum usable range of the laser. A beam is cropped to this value.  -->
    <param name="maxUrange" value="10.0"/>

    <!-- The maximum range of the sensor. If regions with no obstacles within the range of the sensor should appear as free space in the map, set maxUrange < maximum range of the real sensor <= maxRange -->
    <param name="maxRange" value="10.0"/>

    <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
    <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
    <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="minimumScore" value="150.0"/>
    <!-- Number of beams to skip in each scan. -->
    <param name="lskip" value="0"/>

    <param name="srr" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="srt" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="str" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="stt" value="0.02"/>

    <!-- Process a scan each time the robot translates this far  -->
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.1"/>

    <!-- Process a scan each time the robot rotates this far  -->
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.05"/>

    <param name="temporalUpdate" value="-1.0"/>
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>

    <!-- Number of particles in the filter. default 30        -->
    <param name="particles" value="20"/>

    <!-- Initial map size  -->
    <param name="xmin" value="-10.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-10.0"/>
    <param name="xmax" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="10.0"/>

    <!-- Processing parameters (resolution of the map)  -->
    <param name="delta" value="0.1"/>

    <!-- <param name="minimumScore" value="500"/>
    <param name="occ_thresh" value="0.5"/> -->

    <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
    <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>

    <!-- <remap from="scan" to="$(arg namespace)/$(arg scan_topic)"/> -->
    <!-- <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/> -->
    <!-- <remap from="odom" to="odom_rf2o"/> -->
  </node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386419/robot-jumps-after-the-initial-estimate-with-gmapping/) by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-09-13**:
What computer are you running gmapping on? Do you have a network setup or are all the scripts run on single computer?

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2021-09-14**:
I am running them on an OnLogic i5 8th gen PC (https://www.onlogic.com/de-de/ml100g-51/?cpsrc=de_shop_smart&agid=&kw=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkIGKBhCxARIsAINMioIV8R8JYsbrdYhcWBaK63cim2ci7xwFID7QorFOhWhwWsS4sd9nizEaAqxpEALw_wcB)

I run all the scripts on a single computer. I only use my laptop (i5, 8ram) to visualize rviz and access the OnLogic's terminal, by using the "ssh -X ..." command

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-09-14**:
What is your odometry source?

**Comment by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) on 2021-09-14**:
Indeed the mistake was hiding in the odometry source. Thanks for your guidance. I will post it as an answer ;)

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-09-16**:
Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was in the init_pose_from_topic parameter of the rf2o package. I fuse wheel-encoded and rf2o odometry with SLAM using robot_localization package.

I set the init_pose_from_topic parameter of rf2o package to the topic of the wheel encoded odometry, but that result to this jump. I had to set it to empty ( "" )

---

Originally posted by [AlexandrosNic](https://answers.ros.org/users/45283/alexandrosnic/) with karma: 233 on 2021-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-15**:
Glad you were able to fix it.